# why an object of WCF service contract interface can be casted to IClientChannel

Tags: c#, wcf, channelfactory

In [WCF Client Architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729718(v=vs.110).aspx), it says

> When using the ChannelFactory class with a service contract interface, you must cast to the IClientChannel interface to explicitly open, close, or abort the channel

So you create and use the client channel object like this:

```
var cf = new ChannelFactory<ICalculator>(binding, ea);

var channel = cf.CreateChannel();
double result = channel.Add(5.2, 3.5);
Console.WriteLine(channel.GetType()); // outputs ICalculator
Console.WriteLine(result);

((IClientChannel)channel).Close();
```

There are two things that confused me here.

1. The method signaure of `CreateChannel`, as well as the first standard output, indicates that channel variable is of type ICalculator, how can it be converted to `IClientChannel`？
2. The object returned by `CreateChannel` should be certain typeof object that implements whatever interface(s), and `channel.GetType()` should return that exact type, why it returns an interface type？

Answer (score 3):

I was recently was studying the same thing, because I was trying to figure out why I could cast my channel as an ICommunicationObject as I saw some of the WCF source code doing.

basically .NET has the type information it needs at runtime.

let's say we have a class that implements an interface

```
class Foo: IFoo {}
```

you can declare the object like this

```
IFoo instance = new Foo()
```

but you can also cast the instance directly as a Foo()

```
Foo cast = (Foo)instance;
```

Because an object can be cast or converted to its type at runtime.

---

So what is WCF doing?

For fun, try to instantiate a channel factory with your own interface

```
IFoo instance = new ChannelFactory<IFoo>()
```

you'll get a runtime exception.

"InvalidOperationException
Attempted to get contract type for IFoo, but that type is not a ServiceContract, nor does it
inherit a ServiceContract."

When you decorate an interface with the [ServiceContract] attribute, the WCF runtime picks this up and builds all the classes that WCF needs to build your channel.

This includes interfaces like ICommunicationObject, IChannelFactory<TChannel>, IClientChannel, etc.

So although the factory method exposes your instance as an IFoo, at runtime it also has the other interfaces WCF needs to run.

---

Finally, the reason that channel.GetType() returns an ICalculatory, is because GetType() is returning the runtime type of that object. By casting to an IClientChannel, you are performing a type conversion that WCF guarantees will succeed.

Comment: Thanks, @vid. You description about how WCF implements the service contract interface helps me. Could you explain why GetType() returns ICalculator? I still don't get it, if it returns the exact runtime type of the referenced object, then it should return the type information of the type created by WCF runtime.