# In what cases the GetType() method would return type of an interface

Tags: c#

I am asking this because I get an object that is generated by WCF runtime, and calling GetType() on it returns type of an interface. So in case you are not familiar or interested with WCF, this is more specific question.

And this is the related question I asked:
[why an object of WCF service contract interface can be casted to IClientChannel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26082494/why-an-object-of-wcf-service-contract-interface-can-be-casted-to-iclientchannel)

Comment: Don't know anything about this, but does this maybe help? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1e15e6f7-e187-438d-9a75-27e68bc037cf/objgettype-is-returning-an-interface-definition-rather-than-a-class-definition-is-that?forum=netfxbcl

Comment: Thanks @RenniePet, authough I am not ready for understanding that codeproject article, it prevents me from thinking about the underlying model all the time.

Answer (score 1):

I can't catalog all the cases where this might happen, but here's some info on this particular case. The CLR has some facilities for enabling interception of calls in System.Runtime.Remoting. In particular the class `RealProxy` seems to be special. You can use it wrap an object and intercept the calls to methods on an object. This [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn574804.aspx) has a number of details on how to use/implement `RealProxy`. I've found that you can use this to intercept methods like GetType. I suspect WCF is doing this under the hood as well with dynamically generated classes. A demonstration using some of the examples in that article:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(new DynamicProxy(new Calculator(), typeof(ICalculator)).GetTransparentProxy().GetType());
    }
}

public interface ICalculator
{
    double Add(double x, double y);
}

class Calculator : ICalculator
{
    public double Add(double x, double y)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

class DynamicProxy : RealProxy
{
    private readonly object _decorated;
    private readonly Type _reportedType;
    private static readonly MethodInfo GetTypeMethodInfo = typeof(object).GetMethod("GetType");

    public DynamicProxy(object decorated, Type reportedType)
        : base(reportedType)
    {
        _decorated = decorated;
        _reportedType = reportedType;
    }

    private void Log(string msg, object arg = null)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.WriteLine(msg, arg);
        Console.ResetColor();
    }

    public override IMessage Invoke(IMessage msg)
    {
        var methodCall = msg as IMethodCallMessage;
        var methodInfo = methodCall.MethodBase as MethodInfo;
        Log("In Dynamic Proxy - Before executing '{0}'",
          methodCall.MethodName);
        try
        {
            object result;
            if (GetTypeMethodInfo.Equals(methodInfo))
            {
                result = _reportedType;
            }
            else
            {
                result = methodInfo.Invoke(_decorated, methodCall.InArgs);
            }

            Log("In Dynamic Proxy - After executing '{0}' ",
              methodCall.MethodName);
            return new ReturnMessage(result, null, 0,
              methodCall.LogicalCallContext, methodCall);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log(string.Format(
              "In Dynamic Proxy- Exception {0} executing '{1}'", e),
              methodCall.MethodName);
            return new ReturnMessage(e, methodCall);
        }
    }
}
```